# logic apps with multiple sql connections

Tags: azure-logic-apps

i have a scenario as below.

1. retrieving data from topic(xml).
2. finding an element value(for ex: xxx ) from xml (using xpath)
3. depending on the value i need to connect to different sql servers.

i.e. if XXX is 10 then connect to SQLServer_1
if XXX is 20 then connect SQLServer_2

the value is dynamic here. i have 3-4 possible values for XXX and in future it may increase.

I am not able to create a logic app which connects to SQLServers based on the XXX value.

Can someone please help me on this.

Azure sql server

Comment: Are you performing the same action but only sql connections are different ?

Comment: yes and i figured out a way to do it. using triggerBody()['CorrelationId'] in the conenction name..

Comment: @Chitti Are you able to create dynamic SQL connections ?

Comment: yes. and triggerBody()['CorrelationId']  using like this, i am able to do so.